# c++ std::bind universal reference can't compile

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using cb_t = std::function<void ()>;

template<typename CB_T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<cb_t, CB_T>::value, bool> = true>
void
on_my_write(int a, int b, CB_T&& cb) {
    std::cout << "on_my_write:" << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
}
 

template<typename CB_T,  std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<cb_t, CB_T>::value, bool> = true>
void foo(CB_T&& cb) {
    auto b = std::bind(&on_my_write<CB_T>, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::forward<CB_T>(cb));
    b(1, 2);
}

int main() {
  
    foo([]{});

    return 0;
}
```

compile this with command line

```sh
g++ ./try1.cpp -std=c++17
```

gave me:

```sh
./try1.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void foo(CB_T&&) [with CB_T = main()::<lambda()>; typename >std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<std::function<void()>, CB_T>::value, bool>::type <anonymous> = 1]’:

./try1.cpp:39:13:   required from here
./try1.cpp:34:6: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, main()::<lambda()>))(int, int, main()::<lambda()>&&)>) (int, int)’
     b(1, 2);
     ~^~~~~~
In file included from ./try1.cpp:19:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:547:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(int, int, main()::<lambda()>&&); _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, main()::<lambda()>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args)
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:547:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:558:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(int, int, main()::<lambda()>&&); _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, main()::<lambda()>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:558:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:576:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(int, int, main()::<lambda()>&&); _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, main()::<lambda()>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:576:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:588:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(int, int, main()::<lambda()>&&); _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, main()::<lambda()>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:588:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

But if I change `on_my_write(int a, int b, CB_T&& cb)` to `on_my_write(int a, int b, const CB_T& cb)`, then it  will compile and run successfully.

I really don't understand why?

Could anybody explain this to me? thanks a lot!

I've tried several hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: in modern C++ (i see you at least use C++17) lamdas have pratically replaced bind... compilers usually even give better result with lambdas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is slightly tricky. `std::bind` is of course not magical, it has to store the bound parameters somehow and it stores them as values by default, unless requested with `std::ref` argument.

Meaning that in the call`std::bind(...,std::forward<CB_T>(cb))`, the `cb` is used to construct the bound member variable properly using the perfect forwarding.

But, the calling is not done with perfect forwarding sadly, the argument that bind will pass to `on_my_write` is always an l-value. It is not impossible to create `std::bind` version that would forward it and I do not know exactly why is it this way, but a good reason might be that such forwarding would make calling the bound functor multiple times dangerous.

So, since `std::bind` always passes the argument as l-value, you have a couple of options:

1. Remove perfect forwarding and use `on_my_write(int a, int b, const CB_T& cb)` as you did.
2. Remove perfect forwarding and move anyway, use `on_my_write(int a, int b, CB_T& cb)`
   and use `std::move(cb)` inside to consume it. Be careful, this is exactly the case in which the new functor should be called just once.
3. Keep perfect forwarding but do not use it for this call which can be achieved by manually adding a reference:

   ```
   std::bind(&on_my_write<CB_T&>, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2,
          std::forward<CB_T>(cb));
   ```

   This will work thanks to reference collapsing rules and `on_my_write(int a, int b, CB_T& cb)` will be called always. You can still use 2. and move anyway.
4. <sup><sub>Choose me</sub></sup> Forget `std::bind`, use lambda:

   ```
   template<typename CB_T,  std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<cb_t, CB_T>::value, 
   bool> = true>
   void foo(CB_T&& cb) {
       auto b = [&cb](auto a,auto b){return on_my_write(a,b,std::forward<CB_T>(cb));};
       b(1, 2);
   }
   ```

   This will forward `cb` properly, an extra advantage of this solution is that you do not have to deduce `on_my_write` manually.